# Reset a player's progress on a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft server I've just started for a few friends.  We're playing on hard, and I'm going to set it up so that players spawn with a few minimal items to get them going.  Some of them jumped in briefly and logged out after less than 5 minutes last night.  How do I reset their progress so that when next they log in, they spawn as if they have never logged in before and have the items I set new players to spawn with?

I.E., how do I make the server forget that they were ever there?

Comment: For the record, myself and another friend played for some time last night, so I don't want to completely reset the world from scratch.

Comment: Also, this is a hosted server with Exodus hosting, which uses the Multicraft control panel.  I have full access to the server's files via FTP, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you remove the files in the `world\players` and `world\stats` folder, the server will forget that they were there. If this is a bukkit server, there is a `players` folder in each world. Files are named with the ID of the player, so you can delete selectively. To get the ID of a player, open `https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/(playername)` (substitute `(playername)` with the actual player name)

Comment: Also, since Minecraft version 1.7, there is a `world\stats` directory, which contains `playername.json` files. These contain the player's statistics and achievements.

Comment: I can do that, but I'm curious if deleting someone from the players list via the multicraft panel has the same effect. I'd assume so, but do you know for sure?

Comment: @TimCoker I'm not familiar with the multicraft panel, sorry.

Comment: To follow up, the way to do this is by deleting files.  The multicraft panel doesn't delete the files.

Comment: @Kcats: In recent versions of Minecraft, it is no longer usernames that show up, but rather, the UUID value for a given player, since anyone can now change their Minecraft username. In order to reset a player's data now, you would have to look up their UUID number for their current username, match it to the value in `world/players` and `world/stats` and then remove the file.

Comment: @jflory7 I have updated the answer to reflect name changing

Answer (score -5):

On a single player/LAN world I just deleted everything in the minecraft\saves(the world you want to do it on) and only kept the folder that said region and the file that said session.lock and it deleted all player data from every player. But like I said, this will do it to every player. I don't know If that is what you wanted but I hope this could help.

Comment: Please re-read question. If you tell users not to do what you said I will give you a point for doing the right thing. I can't down vote or I might. This is way off.