# Can I reset my progress when playing on a server I don't control?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing on someone else's server and have died in an inaccessible spot under water. Upon respawning, I don't get back the introductory items a new player would get. Is there any way I could get a new character/reset my progress on a server myself, without involving the owner?

This is *not* a duplicate of [that question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/157831/84026). The other question is about resetting progress of a player on a server you control. My question is how to start from scratch when I'm just a user, not a server-owner.

Comment: What server is it, if we knew we could look into that. Oh and good question +1.

Comment: @Jonoco98 http://www.obsidianprison.com

Comment: I did no research, but I'm pretty sure the answer is going to be "No" to reset a player you need to remove a specific file on the server, and for that you need access to the files.

Comment: Ok, by just browsing through the forums, I don't see a way to reset your progress. With this being said, try to contact a server admin and tell them your situation.

Comment: To reset a player all you need to do is goto the server's player folder and delete your player's `.dat` file.

Comment: @Jonco98 I don't run that server.

Comment: I know just in case you ever get one, I have one, only reason I know how.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is asking an owner to delete your `player.dat`. This wouldn't work on a plugin server because individual plugins often have player data files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.
There's of course the playername.dat in the server folder which could be deleted/modified, but you can't access the file without the help of the server owner.
But: You mentioned "introductory items", maybe you're able to get them by checking if its a kit? (for example "/kit starter").
Also you could of course login with another account, especially if the server has set offline-mode to true, you would be able to choose another username and then join the server without re-buying minecraft.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for! My bad for presuming a solution without looking at the problem first.