# Play as a new character on the old map in single player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to delete my character progress in single player, while keeping the map  and all my changes to it the same? I have seen [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157831/reset-a-players-progress-on-a-server), but it does not work. I am running 1.8.1. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Also, I don't see a `kittycat3141.dat` file, I see a file with a random filename.

Comment: Hmm... Checking now. Can you screenshot that folder? (No .dat file)

Comment: OK. See that folder saying playerdata? Back it up first, but delete it.

Comment: Might want to do the same with the stats folder as well. (Holds player stats by the looks of it)

Comment: @FinnRayment For some reason it's not working. I deleted both folders and I still have my inventory. It recreates them when I open the world again.

Comment: I'm assuming those folders regenerated themselves?

Comment: @FinnRayment Yes, when I opened the world. I had closed Minecraft to delete the folders.

Comment: OK. Try just deleting the insides of that playerdata folder only.

Comment: @FinnRayment Still not working. Is Minecraft storing this information somewhere else or something? I'm deleting the files and they are reappearing.

Comment: according to [this page](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format) the .data file in the playerdata folder is just for servers (which a singleplayer world can easily be promoted to) however level.dat (found in the world's [root directory](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/.minecraft)) stores the state of the singleplayer player, maybe back up your world and delete this file along with the playerdata folder and see if that works

Comment: Erhh... Would you like to move this discussion to chat for consistency? Otherwise i'll just keep replying here.

Comment: Here. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19711/reset-progress-in-single-player I advise you join too @Memor-X You could be of some help.

Comment: can you specify if you want a fresh world with the same terrain or the same world but a new player

Comment: @ModDL Same world, fresh player.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197686/changing-minecraft-playerdata-when-transferring-a-saved-game-open-to-lan). This is about a player that moved a local world save from one player to another, and got the inventory of the original owner of the world.

Comment: Good Q&A. Upvote.

Comment: Might want to edit the question to clarify if you mean "without changing the world, including any changes made to it as a result of the player's interaction" as opposed to "start the same world from scratch. The former is done via file editing, the latter is done via building a new world with the same seed. Out of interest, I believe MC edit may have a 'delete user' feature, but I'm too busy to check at the minute. On a multiplayer server it is merely a matter of deleting a user file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After lots of testing, I've figured this out.

Deleting `playerdata` will not work because `level.dat` contains your singleplayer player info and supersedes whatever is in `playerdata`. However, `level.dat` does not just contain player data, so deleting it will mess up the world. Here's the solution:

1. You need an NBT editor. I used NBTExplorer.
2. Close Minecraft while you edit the world
3. Delete the `Player` node from level.dat
4. Delete your file in `playerdata`
5. (optional, if you want your stats removed as well) Delete your file in `stats`
6. Reopen Minecraft and play in a restarted world

Comment: Getting technical is always the answer. Plus the NBT format is one of the best file formats ever invented, I take my hat off to Notch for inventing it.

Comment: @Pharap well, it's just JSON...

Comment: @Quentin It's not quite JSON, it's a binary format rather than plaintext, which means it has the simplicity of JSON but makes it easier to parse and it generally takes less memory.

Comment: @Pharap wait, so "NBT" actually designates the binary-stored form, not the language itself ? That sure was quite blurry for me...

Comment: @Quentin NBT is stored more efficiently than JSON, almost like a compressed version of it. They can store the same data.

Comment: @Quentin You can read Notch's original (unofficial) specification for the NBT format here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110723210920/http://www.minecraft.net/docs/NBT.txt It's an interesting read for any game geek, particularly one who enjoys programming or minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

Jump into a large pool of lava. Your inventory and experience will go with you. A few attempts with the contents of various chests should complete this process fairly quickly (far quicker than posting on the internet and trying out various hacks).

Answer (score 2):

Generate the world with the same seed as the first world. Assuming the world was generated with a recent version, this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what the OP was asking (I said the same thing), the OP was trying to find a way of keeping a world the same (with buildings and such built by the player), and resetting their inventory, experience etc.

Comment: @Ben I see. This _really_ needs rewording, it totally wasn't clear.

Comment: Um. Jump in lava? Unless it's hardcore, I guess.