# How to stop being dead in hardcore minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I've been playing a lot of hardcore minecraft lately, it's fun to *need* to be careful. Unfortunately an out of game event occurred that needed my immediate attention, which lead to my death in game. I've still got the save file, but when I log in a see the "You are dead" screen:[image]

Not actually from me, just for explanation purposes.

I'm comfortable editing the files with NBTExplorer but I'm not sure which files to edit. I died in the nether, but I've managed thus far to move myself to my spawn points in the overworld and give myself 19 hp. But I'm still dead. Any advice? I'd like to keep the game in hardcore mode if possible!

Comment: The only suggestion I can make is to get the seed and try over. The whole point of playing on hardcore is that you *will* lose your world when you die. If you don't want this to happen, don't play hardcore.

Comment: @Ben It's hardly unfair for someone to say "I want to play hardcore, but if somebody breaks down my front door while I'm fighting a ghast and I die because of it, I'm not going to count that death". Maybe you like to be 100% strict when playing on hardcore, but that doesn't mean it's wrong for OP to try to work around this here.

Comment: @Chris Not saying it's not unfair. I've died plenty of times to stupid things. I got pushed off a ledge by a cow once.

Comment: An important skill for hardcore players is hitting Escape as part of your "look away from the screen" routine.  I'm slowly building that muscle memory and I'm finding that no matter real-life distractions are taking place around me I often pause the game without realizing I've done so.  I'll come back and assume my save is lost but then discover I hit Escape without even thinking about it just because I always do so.  Very helpful, even though it takes a while to train (and is counter-intuitive for people who play online a lot, where it doesn't pause).

Comment: @Ben Any in game cause of death is fine, this isn't my first try on hardcore skyblock - but needing to instantly AFK does not IMO warrant loss of file.

Comment: My best advice is to ask on the minecraft mod development forums. what you need to do is modify the nbt player data so it basically never shows that you died. mod devs would have an insight into how to revert the nbt data and perform any modifications.

Comment: I think if you host that progress and let someone join that same progress than it is possible for you to play the same world on other's device (for a change of cource)

Comment: [Joke] This reminds me of the famous line in Wargames:  The only winning move is not to play [hardcore].  Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the method which I think is the best to do this using [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac?comment=1) (or whatever programs that allow you to edit NBT files. See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors/Inventory_editors) for the list).

1. Back up your hardcore skyblock folder
2. Make a second hardcore skyblock
3. Load up the game, then exit
4. Open both game saves in the NBT program (2 separate instances is fine)
5. Replace any values on your failed skyblock (that are not inventory based) with those from the new skyblock - only the values in the folders marked "Player".
6. Load up you 'failed' skyblock and continue your saga.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

Now that there's spectator mode, click that instead of delete world when you die. Once in spectator mode, open to LAN and type command /gamemode 0. You go back to hardcore survival.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually get your world and all your items back by doing the following:

1. click spectate world
2. open the Game Menu
3. click open to LAN
4. click allow cheats ''ON''
5. do `/gamemode creative` or `/gamemode survival`

Happy gaming.

Answer (score 1):

if you keep a reasonably recent copy of the level.dat file on hand you can replace the one running in your world file and then be not dead.

also sometimes if you alt+f4 quick enough after you die you can sometimes still join in right before you died.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the above (which should work, by the way)

When I was admin over an agrarian skies map there were people who died and were very sad about it, so I know this "works" in that situation. I didn't want them to get off scott free, so I forced a hard reset on their character by deleting them.

Steps to delete the player:

1. back up the entire world.
2. Shut down the game (exit)
3. delete the player .dat files from the folder in "world\players"
4. delete the player .dat data in the "world\stats" folder.
5. restart the game
6. play the game

I just realized my answer duplicates one found here:
[Reset a player's progress on a server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157831/reset-a-players-progress-on-a-server)

Comment: This won't work on singleplayer because level.dat overrides player files.

Comment: It doesn't work unless you are not running the game while you do it. I did it successfully with Agrarian Skies. I don't know if that mod pack does something to enable it, but it's worth a try because it's a little easier and less technical than learning how to use an NBT editor. However, an NBT editor will give you more reliable results.

Answer (score -1):

Open to LAN -> Allow Cheats: ON -> Type: /gamemode 0 -> (grab stuff [optional]) -> Quit to title and rejoin -> ENJOY